# Remove outside gutters in Neat 2

Tags: sass, neat

I've upgraded to [Bourbon Neat v2](http://neat.bourbon.io/) which includes the addition of gutters on the left and right side of the container grid.

[image: Neat Layout Screenshot]

In `v1` I could use `block-collapse` in the [span-columns](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/1.8.0/#span-columns) mixin to eat the gutters either side of the element, however, in `v2` this mixin has been removed. There is a [grid-collapse](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#grid-collapse) function in `v2` but that doesn't quite work as I expected.  My current markup is as below (reduced for brevity):

```
.wrapper {
  @include grid-container; // columns: 12, gutter: 1rem
  @include grid-visual(lime);
}

.sidebar {
  @include grid-columns(2 of 12);
}

.container {
  @include grid-columns(10 of 12);
}
```

How do I remove the outer gutters, an collapse the gutter between column 2 & 3 so that my sidebar and container sit next to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were correct in looking at the `grid-collapse` mixin to take care of this.

To do a flush grid like the one you described, your markup would be:

```
.wrapper {
  @include grid-container;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  @include grid-collapse;
}

.sidebar {
  @include grid-column(2 of 12);
}

.container {
  @include grid-column(10 of 12);
}
```

Comment: It seems that this behaves a bit strangely. If I have markup: `body > main.wrapper > section.inner > .sidebar + .container` this will not give me a flush grid. However, if I do `body > main > section.wrapper > div.inner > .sidebar + .container` it will give me a flush grid. Any thoughts on this? I'd much rather not have to add extra markup when it's not necessary.

Comment: Ok disregard that comment. Apparently I had a max-width for one of my elements and completely missed it when troubleshooting. Thanks for your answer, it works.

Comment: Works
https://s29.postimg.org/vanq8y0if/neat-visual.png but You need to remember to move `@include grid-visual` to `.wrapper-inner`, if You using one.

Comment: Thanks @whmii. Your solution worked for me. I was struggling on how to remove the outside gutter spaces.

Answer (score 0):

just expanding on the top answer, you need to also make sure to include `grid-collapse` within `grid-media` declarations when using multiple grids due to the fact that `grid-collapse` is based on your gutter values for each grid.

```css
.wrapper {
  @include grid-container;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  @include grid-collapse;

  @include grid-media($sm-neat-grid, $md-neat-grid, $lg-neat-grid) {
    @include grid-collapse;
  }
}

.sidebar {
  @include grid-column(1 of 1);

  @include grid-media($sm-neat-grid, $md-neat-grid) {
    @include grid-column(3 of 12)
  }

  @include grid-media($lg-neat-grid) {
    @include grid-column(5 of 15)
  }
}

.container {
  @include grid-column(1 of 1);

  @include grid-media($sm-neat-grid, $md-neat-grid) {
    @include grid-column(9 of 12)
  }

  @include grid-media($lg-neat-grid) {
    @include grid-column(10 of 15)
  }
}
```

by the way, my example is using a modified version of `grid-media` that allows declaring multiple grids that will share the same values but differ in gutter sizes:

```css
// overrides bourbon-neat grid-media to include more than one grid
@mixin grid-media($grids...) {
  @each $grid in $grids {
    $_media: _retrieve-neat-setting($grid, media);
    $_query: _neat-parse-media($_media);

    @media #{$_query} {
      $_default-neat-grid: $neat-grid;
      $neat-grid: map-merge($neat-grid, $grid) !global;
      @content;
      $neat-grid: $_default-neat-grid !global;
    }
  }
}
```

can't for the life of me remember where I got it from but I've used it in all my projects