# Full width, 50/50 layout in Neat 2.x?

Tags: css, neat

I'm trying to achieve a 50/50 panel layout using Bourbon Neat 2.x, where the left panel is going to have a background colour, but grid margins are causing me some issues.

I initially just had the standard `grid-container` as a parent, with two divs using the `@include grid-column(6)` mixin. Trouble is, that left a margin at the left and right of the grid so the 50% background colour panel didn't quite work.

I then tried adding the `grid-collapse` mixin to try and get rid of the margins ([codepen example](https://codepen.io/PaulAik/pen/rGqWya)), but that seems to have the effect of making the page > 100% width, leading to a horizontal scroll for the user.

Is there a simple way to achieve this layout, or should I use a custom grid definition for the panels with no margins at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove outside gutters in Neat 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625159/remove-outside-gutters-in-neat-2)

Answer (score 0):

Neat can cover this use case but it requires slightly more html. the trick is that the object with the class `grid-collapse` (`.container` in your example) needs a wrapper around it with `width: 100%; overflow: hidden;`.

Here is a question that also answers this → [Remove outside gutters in Neat 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625159/remove-outside-gutters-in-neat-2)